# Best way to tell what application/process is using swap?

Tags: swap

I have 16G RAM, and 8G swap partition. I'm running Unity 17.04. I have a problem where my `buff/cache` goes to 11M, and my `swap used` goes to around 3500. Previously I almost never used any swap space, and I've never monitored the buff/cache.

I believe that it's an application with a memory leak, but I could be wrong.

Simple question. Is there any easy way to determine with application/process is, or has been, using swap?

[image]

Comment: One other possibility is that [`vm.swappiness`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) might be set high, which can push things into swap if the OS thinks it won't need them for a long time, even if there's plenty of open RAM.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex hum... I wonder... pre 17.04 I had vm.swappiness=10... but after I upgraded to 17.04 I set it back to the default of 60. I wonder if that's about the time that I noticed this? I may have to set it back and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex well, I played with vm.swappiness, and finally settled on =10 again, like it was before. My buff/cache usage is still 11-12G after a few days, but I guess that's normal, as long as the **avail Mem** stays high. If you make your comment into an answer, I can vote/accept it.

Answer (score 6):

You can find that how much does special process uses swap partition by this command :

```
cat /proc/"PID"/status | grep "^VmSwap"
```

And you can find `PID` by this command:

```
ps -A | grep "Application_name"
```

But if you want to find which processes are using the swap partition, you can use this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in /proc/*/status ; do
    vmswap=$(cat $i | grep "^VmSwap")
    echo "$vmswap" | grep -qv ' 0 kB'
    if [ $? == 0 ] && [ "$vmswap" != "" ] ; then
        echo "$i : $vmswap"
    fi
done
```

Then you can find the application name from its PID that's returned by the script.

**Update**: I changed this script to create log file every 10 second (you can change the time) and in that file you can see many processes from the moment you run this script up to now:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
touch ~/swap_process_usage.log
while true ; do
    echo -e "************************************\nSwap's process in count $counter " >> ~/swap_process_usage.log
    for i in /proc/*/status ; do
        vmswap=$(cat $i | grep "^VmSwap")
        echo "$vmswap" | grep -qv ' 0 kB'
        if [ $? == 0 ] && [ "$vmswap" != "" ] ; then
            pid=$(echo "$i" | tr -d /proc/ | tr -d status)
            proc_name=$(ps -p $pid -o comm=)
            echo "$proc_name : $pid : $vmswap" >> ~/swap_process_usage.log
        fi
    done
    sleep 10s
    counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

And you can set this script to run at **startup** so it creates log every time.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try as soon as my swap creeps up again. I'll come back and vote/accept then.

Comment: My swap crept up again, and I tried your script (and another one that I found) and both reported back nothing. It seems like they may only report if the process is currently active and currently using swap? +1 vote. I'm currently retrying vm.swappiness setting.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for your reply. yes this script shows that which process uses your `swap partition` , because you said that " Is there any easy way to determine with application/process is, or has been, using swap?" But if your swap is not be used this script isn't be helpful and reported back nothing . Is your swap used ?

Comment: Yes, I tried the script when it showed swap partition usage. I'm guessing that if swap usage is not **currently actively** used, the scripts report nothing. In other words, the scripts won't show what used swap in the past, if there's no current activity.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for your reply. I've changed my script to shows the **past swap** process. Please try this script

Comment: Thanks for the script update. As soon as my swap creeps up, I'll give it a try. Right now I'm testing a vm.swappiness value change.

Comment: @heynnema please put this script to your startups. Because it make a log files  **from the moment you run this script** up to stop it. So you can't check the past process if don't run it before.

Comment: Just a brief update for you... before 17.04 I had vm.swappiness=10... after the 17.04 update I let it set this back to 60... and I guess that's when I noticed the problem with swap and buff/cache. So I've played with vm.swappiness again, and settled on =10 again, and swap is now 0. **buff/cache** gets to 11-12G after a few days, but as long as **avail Mem** stays high, I guess that's normal. Thanks for your time and scripts.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for your reply and your brief update ; yes it's normal,  but if you want to know which process use your swap (as you want in this question) , you can use my script.